# Use Java to implement a binary search algorithm to search for a specific element in an ordered array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search

Suppose you have an ordered array of integers and you need to find the index of a specific element in the array. You decide to use the binary search algorithm, which is a commonly used search algorithm for ordered arrays.

Write a Java program that implements the binary search algorithm to search for a specific element in the array. Your program should take the following inputs: The ordered array of integers and the element to search for in the array. Your program should return the index of the element in the array, or -1 if the element is not found.

Be sure to explain the logic behind the binary search algorithm and how it works in your implementation.

Code I tried:

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int x) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = arr.length - 1;
        
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            
            if (arr[mid] == x) {
                return mid;
            } else if (arr[mid] < x) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        
        // element not found
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int x = 5;
        int result = binarySearch(arr, x);
        
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element found at index " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question to ask?

Comment: When I run the code in your question, it prints: _Element found at index 2_ That seems correct to me, so what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the implementation of `binarySearch()` in `java.util.Arrays`:

```
private static int binarySearch0(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int key) {
    int low = fromIndex;
    int high = toIndex - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BinarySearch in Java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 5);
        System.out.println("Element found at ->  "+index);
    }
}
```

output:
Element found at ->  2

Comment: *Write a Java program that implements the binary search algorithm* - How does this implement a binary search algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this implementation of binary search code in java.

```
import java.util.*;
public class binarysearch {
    
    public static int bs(int a[],int key){
        int start = 0 , end=a.length-1;
        while(start<=end){
            int mid = (start+end)/2;

            if(key==a[mid]){
                return mid;
            }

            if(key<a[mid]){
                end = mid-1;
            }
              else {
                start = mid+1;
              }
        } 
          return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        int size=s.nextInt();
        int n[]=new int[size];

        System.out.println("Enter elements of array");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          n[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
          System.out.println("Enter the number you want to find");
      
          int key = s.nextInt();
          
          System.out.println("Number found at index" + " " + bs(n, key));
        
          s.close();
    }
}
```